# ng-show not working properly atfer ng-init

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my code

```
<div ng-init="$scope.bot_assistance='false'">
    <label for="switch">Bot Assistance:
        <input type="checkbox" id="switch" ng-model="$scope.bot_assistance">
    </label><br/>
    <p>Value:-{{ $scope.bot_assistance }}</p>
    <div ng-hide="$scope.bot_assistance">Bot Assist Disabled</div>
</div>
```

After my page loads I can see the value of `$scope.bot_assistance='false'` but why is my `ng-hide` evaluating to be `true` and not showing up on the page. 
Also it shows up div block after I check and uncheck again. So I guess it sets `ng-hide=true` after checking the checkbox and shows up after again clicking the checkbox making  `<div ng-hide="$scope.bot_assistance">` to be false which is what I want it to work but After page load it doesn't show the ng-hide block. Why is it so can anyone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really use $scope in your template?

Comment: Why is `$scope` being used in view? Also , this is not what `ng-init` is for. Do that initialization in controller. Read `ngInit` docs

Comment: I needed the initialization outside the controller so used ng-init with $scope

Comment: Why do you need it outside? The view can't be compiled until after controller runs to create scope. Setting defaults in view to pass back to controller is just totally backwards

Comment: Even if you need it outside the controller - use `app.run()` life-cycle hook or provide the value using a service/constant.

Comment: if this code runs probably you're using  a controllerAs syntax with an alias "$scope" for the controller..sure not a good practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not use `$scope` inside the template (are you really using `$scope.$scope` inside your controller?)
2. [Do not initialize the initial value with `ngInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)
3. Do not initialize boolean variable with a string value `bot_assistance='false'`

Comment: Thanks @Stanislav Kvitash for your answer and explanations